# How to change URL in the address bar of a browser?

Tags: url, browser, content-management-system, dns

I bought to domains, let's say a.com and b.com. Then I also bought some webspace from a hoster. The domain a.com is pointing to the top level folder of my webspace (/). The domain b.com points to a folder on level deeper (/folderB).

Now if I'm using the domain b.com to access /folderB it works as intented. Then I installed a small CMS their and i can use it. But unfortunately if a surf through the sites, the URL always displays www.a.com/folderB/something insteand of www.b.com/something.

Any hints how to solve this?

Edit: I using this CMS: http://www.cmsmadesimple.org/

Comment: Which CMS? This is probably a configuration setting.

Answer (score 0):

You could deploy Apache `.htaccess` + `mod_rewrite` for this if it's on for your server, which I'm sure it is. Then just with a few `RewriteRule`s you could pull it off :)

You'll find plenty of stuff on Google and here about it I'm sure.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't easily use `RewriteRule` across domains. OP wants `b.com/.*` to point to `a.com/folderB/$1`. Some kind of `CNAME Record`, perhaps combined with a `RewriteRule`, is probably in order, but I'll let the DNS gurus answer this.